# Adjusting spacing in a Highcharts chart dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here's my problem:

I have multiple charts under various tabs. After loading a chart, I add SVG text and rect to display an additional legend after the plot. Each chart might have a different legend that can vary in length, so the space required may vary.

I use the spacingBottom value to allow space for the legend to be displayed. I could set this value manually before the chart is loaded (as in the example below), but it can be lots of work if the text in the legends are changed.

What can I do to set the spacingBottom value to the required number based on the height of the legend container?

The example can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aNLSz/1/

```
$(function () {
    var myLegends = [
        '*: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    '<strong>NP</strong>: Pellentesque in sapien diam, ac tristique dolor. Curabitur sit amet est nunc, eget egestas neque.',
    '<strong>NP</strong>: Pellentesque sollicitudin ultrices tristique. Aenean pharetra nulla eget turpis tincidunt vulputate. Sed pulvinar nisi et ante iaculis vulputate.',
    '<strong>*</strong> Donec elit enim, fermentum sit amet varius a, feugiat at nunc. Aliquam ac mi eu nunc dapibus interdum. ',
    '<strong>**</strong> Proin rutrum tincidunt sollicitudin. Vestibulum sit amet dui odio. Suspendisse potenti. Integer accumsan iaculis est ut tempor. ',

];

function drawLegend(chart, legends) {
    //Si il y a des légendes, les ajouter
    var selectedLegends = '';
    var myBoxHeight = 12;
    textY = chart.chartHeight - chart.options.chart.spacingBottom + 25;
    if (legends.length != 0) {

        var counter = 0;
        for (counter = 0; counter < legends.length; counter++) {
            legendNum = legends[counter];
            selectedLegends += myLegends[legendNum] + '<br/>';
        }
        selectedLegends += '<span style="color: #EEEEEE">.</span><br/>';

    }

        var text = chart.renderer.text(selectedLegends, 15, textY).attr({
            zIndex: 5
        }).css({
            color: '#222222',
            fontSize: '9.5px',
            lineHeight: '12px',
            width: (Math.min(chart.chartWidth - 30,650)) + 'px'
        }).attr({
                'xml:space': 'preserve'
            }).add();
        var box = text.getBBox();

        var legendContainer = chart.renderer.rect(box.x - 5, box.y - 5, box.width + 10, box.height + 10, 5)
            .attr({
            fill: '#EEEEEE',
            stroke: '#B8B8B8',
            'stroke-width': 1,
            zIndex: 4
        })
            .add();
        console.log (legendContainer.height);
        //Need to do something like this:
        //chart.options.chart.spacingBottom = legendContainer.height + 10;

}

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            borderWidth: 1,
            spacingBottom: 100,
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            events: {
                        load: function () {
                            drawLegend(this, [1,2,3]);
                        }
                    }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {   
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });
});
```

Maybe there is also a better way to manage this problem outside of the spacingBottom option?

Comment: According to this: http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=17917#p73688 I think is not possibile to change programmatically that property; I tried redraw with no luck, destroy and reinit the chart seems too extreme!

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to think of a different way to do it, since I need the chart to draw the legend, and I need the legend to draw the chart with the appropriate spacing... chicken and egg problem.

Comment: @TheJakester did you find the solution for your problem? I am facing the same thing